# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' can't solve with len(list)

Tags: python

I have this simple problem and I have looked similar responses. The problem is that apparently I'm comparing a list with an int and many say that the solution is just to use len(list). The thing is that I did that and the problem stays the same. What is weird though, is that if I change > for < the problem is solved. The thing, of course, is that I need >, not <. If I change the positions of the elements. Happens the other way around.

The exercise is this:

-Make a list with 3 employee names

-Make another list and put in a sublist the days of the month of their absence in the workplace.

-Print the names of the employees and the days he/she were absent
 Show the employee with the quantity of inasistances

-Show the name -or the names- with the employees that were absent less days.

**Here is the problem**

```
employees = ["Nicolás", "Gonzalo", "Tomás"]

absences = [[1, 5, 9], [2], [3, 6, 12, 17]]

for x in range(len(employees)):
    print(employees[x], absences[x])

for x in range(len(employees)):
    print(employees[x], len(absences[x]))

minorposition = 0
less_absences = int(len(absences[0]))
quantity = 1


for x in range(1, len(employees)):
    absences_per_emp = len(absences[x])

    if less_absences > absences_per_emp:              -----> here is the problem
        less_absences = absences[x]
        minorposition = x
    elif less_absences == absences[x]:
        quantity = quantity + 1

if quantity == 1:
    print("The employee with less absences is:")
    print(employees[minorposition])
else:
    print("The employees with minor absences:")
    for x in range(len(employees)):
        if absences[x] == menor:
            print(employees[x])
```

EDIT: Now I discover sth, if I replace the variable with what's on it, the code runs just fine:

```
empleados = ["Nicolás", "Gonzalo", "Tomás"]

faltas = [[1, 5, 9], [2], [3, 6, 12, 17]]

posmenor = 0
menor = len(faltas[0])
cantidad = 1

for x in range(1, len(empleados)):
    if menor > len(faltas[x]):              If I change the menor variable here 
        menor = faltas[x]                    for len(faltas[0]) the code runs
        posmenor = x                          correctly. Why this happens?
    elif menor == faltas[x]:
        cantidad = cantidad + 1
```

Comment: Can you translate the variable names into English? It's hard to understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Aside from the code you provided, can you explain what your code is actually trying to solve? Can you provide an example input and the desired output?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: `menor` is initially an `int`, but later gets set to `faltas[x]` which is a `list`

Comment: So this it's what it feels when somebedy spot yout mistake. You are a genius. Yes, I know, maybe it's a pretty simple code but I'm just beggining. Thank you very much you all for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you first assign `menor` to `len(faltas[x])` which is an integer, so the first iteration of your for loop will work fine; but then you reassign `menor` to `faltas[x]` which is an array. You should instead assign it to `len(faltas[x])` as you did the first time:

```
for x in range(1, len(empleados)):
    if menor > len(faltas[x]): 
        menor = len(faltas[x])
        posmenor = x 
    elif menor == faltas[x]:
        cantidad = cantidad + 1
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for taking the time